# Display total count of products in orders of a specific order status

Tags: php, shortcode, database, mysql

I have an oddly specific challenge, displaying the total count of products in orders of a specific order status. So let's say there's 52 orders with the order status "Processing", I'm trying to retrieve a total count of line items in those orders to then display on the front end.

Example: "Customers like you are playing with **6,829** Fidget Spinners right now!"

Where the number would essentially be a total count of line items in orders with the "Completed" order status.

I think I understand how to achieve this from a logical standpoint — run a query to filter the database for orders of a specific order status, then retrieve the total line items in each order, and add those all together, but I'm struggling to understand how that translates in code, I'm a front end dev.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

@lukecav has posted a snippet previously that almost does the job:

https://gist.github.com/lukecav/05afef12feaf980c121da9afb9291ad5

If we change the column fetched to "order_item_id", it fetches the number of unique order items that match the criteria:

```
function get_order_items_by_product_id( $product_id, $order_status = array( 'wc-completed' ) ){
    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT order_items.order_item_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", $order_status ) . "' )
        AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_value = '$product_id'
    ");

    return $results;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It fetches order IDs with the right filter but doesn't do the counting / aggregation I don't think.

Comment: Edited with a slight change :)